# Array sorting efficiency... Beginner need advice

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'll start by saying I am very much a beginner programmer, this is essentially my first real project outside of using learning material. I've been making a 'Simon Says' style game (the game where you repeat the pattern generated by the computer) using C# and XNA, the actual game is complete and working fine but while creating it, I wanted to also create a 'top 10' scoreboard. The scoreboard would record player name, level (how many 'rounds' they've completed) and combo (how many buttons presses they got correct), the scoreboard would then be sorted by combo score. This led me to XML, the first time using it, and I eventually got to the point of having an XML file that recorded the top 10 scores. The XML file is managed within a scoreboard class, which is also responsible for adding new scores and sorting scores. Which gets me to the point... I'd like some feedback on the way I've gone about sorting the score list and how I could have done it better, I have no other way to gain feedback =(. I know .NET features Array.Sort() but I wasn't too sure of how to use it as it's not just a single array that needs to be sorted. When a new score needs to be entered into the scoreboard, the player name and level also have to be added. These are stored within an 'array of arrays' (10 = for 'top 10' scores)

```
scoreboardComboData = new int[10]; // Combo

scoreboardTextData = new string[2][];
scoreboardTextData[0] = new string[10]; // Name
scoreboardTextData[1] = new string[10]; // Level as string
```

The scoreboard class works as follows:
- Checks to see if 'scoreboard.xml' exists, if not it creates it
- Initialises above arrays and adds any player data from scoreboard.xml, from previous run
- when AddScore(name, level, combo) is called the sort begins
- Another method can also be called that populates the XML file with above array data

The sort checks to see if the new score (combo) is less than or equal to any recorded scores within the scoreboardComboData array (if it's greater than a score, it moves onto the next element). If so, it moves all scores below the score it is less than or equal to down one element, essentially removing the last score and then places the new score within the element below the score it is less than or equal to. If the score is greater than all recorded scores, it moves all scores down one and inserts the new score within the first element. If it's the only score, it simply adds it to the first element. When a new score is added, the Name and Level data is also added to their relevant arrays, in the same way. What a tongue twister. Below is the AddScore method, I've added comments in the hope that it makes things clearer O_o. You can get the actual source file [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/?jfuefegiliqxip5). Below the method is an example of the quickest way to add a score to follow through with a debugger.

```
    public static void AddScore(string name, string level, int combo)
    {
        // If the scoreboard has not yet been filled, this adds another 'active'
        // array element each time a new score is added. The actual array size is
        // defined within PopulateScoreBoard() (set to 10 - for 'top 10'
        if (totalScores < scoreboardComboData.Length)
            totalScores++;

        // Does the scoreboard even need sorting?
        if (totalScores > 1)
        {
            for (int i = totalScores - 1; i > - 1; i--)
            {
                // Check to see if score (combo) is greater than score stored in 
                // array
                if (combo > scoreboardComboData[i] && i != 0)
                {
                    // If so continue to next element
                    continue;
                }

                // Check to see if score (combo) is less or equal to element 'i'
                // score && that the element is not the last in the
                // array, if so the score does not need to be added to the scoreboard
                else if (combo <= scoreboardComboData[i] && i != scoreboardComboData.Length - 1)
                {
                    // If the score is lower than element 'i' and greater than the last
                    // element within the array, it needs to be added to the scoreboard. This is achieved
                    // by moving each element under element 'i' down an element. The new score is then inserted
                    // into the array under element 'i'
                    for (int j = totalScores - 1; j > i; j--)
                    {
                        // Name and level data are moved down in their relevant arrays
                        scoreboardTextData[0][j] = scoreboardTextData[0][j - 1];
                        scoreboardTextData[1][j] = scoreboardTextData[1][j - 1];
                        // Score (combo) data is moved down in relevant array
                        scoreboardComboData[j] = scoreboardComboData[j - 1];
                    }

                    // The new Name, level and score (combo) data is inserted into the relevant array under element 'i'
                    scoreboardTextData[0][i + 1] = name;
                    scoreboardTextData[1][i + 1] = level;
                    scoreboardComboData[i + 1] = combo;
                    break;
                }

                // If the method gets the this point, it means that the score is greater than all scores within
                // the array and therefore cannot be added in the above way. As it is not less than any score within
                // the array.
                else if (i == 0)
                {
                    // All Names, levels and scores are moved down within their relevant arrays
                    for (int j = totalScores - 1; j != 0; j--)
                    {
                        scoreboardTextData[0][j] = scoreboardTextData[0][j - 1];
                        scoreboardTextData[1][j] = scoreboardTextData[1][j - 1];
                        scoreboardComboData[j] = scoreboardComboData[j - 1];
                    }

                    // The new number 1 top name, level and score, are added into the first element
                    // within each of their relevant arrays.
                    scoreboardTextData[0][0] = name;
                    scoreboardTextData[1][0] = level;
                    scoreboardComboData[0] = combo;

                    break;
                }

                // If the methods get to this point, the combo score is not high enough
                // to be on the top10 score list and therefore needs to break
                break;
            }
        }

        // As totalScores < 1, the current score is the first to be added. Therefore no checks need to be made
        // and the Name, Level and combo data can be entered directly into the first element of their relevant
        // array.
        else
        {
            scoreboardTextData[0][0] = name;
            scoreboardTextData[1][0] = level;
            scoreboardComboData[0] = combo;
        }


    }
}
```

Example for adding score:

```
    private static void Initialize()
    {
        scoreboardDoc = new XmlDocument();
        if (!File.Exists("Scoreboard.xml"))
            GenerateXML("Scoreboard.xml");

        PopulateScoreBoard("Scoreboard.xml");

        // ADD TEST SCORES HERE!
        AddScore("EXAMPLE", "10", 100);
        AddScore("EXAMPLE2", "24", 999);

        PopulateXML("Scoreboard.xml");
    }
```

In it's current state the source file is just used for testing, initialize is called within main and PopulateScoreBoard handles the majority of other initialising, so nothing else is needed, except to add a test score.

I thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a programming tip, you should replace the 3 different arrays with a single array of Score Objects, each of these objects would have all 3 properties you mentioned (Name, Level and Score). You can then create a comparator-like function (based on the score attribute) for it which can be used to sort it via the `Arrays.Sort()` method.

If you want to keep you current 3 arrays then you can look up sorting algorithms here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms and just make it so that any changes are done to the 3 arrays simultaneously instead of one by one (since you keep the data in them synchronized by index).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even consider creating an object to store player properties. It'll give me something new to play with tomorrow :).

Comment: @SoleSoft: No problem, make sure the object implements `IComparable` like @P.R. mentioned and create the comparator function otherwise you won't be able to sort the array containing them using the `Arrays.Sort()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider placing your user name, level, and score in a separate class (let's call it ScoreBoardEntry) that inherits from IComparable and then write a comparator. This will allow you to use the built in sort function of List and will be a neater solution than just writing your own.

Your code should look something like this:

1) Create/load a List < ScoreBoardEntry> with all the previous scores

2) push the new score into it

3) Sort List

4) Print only first 10 entries

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for you.  I've been learning some new-ish type C# stuff like linq, IEnumerable, and yield and kind of wanted to put them together, so hopefully it helps.

you might like the snippet editor i used - [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - it's good for learning/experimenting

```
void Main()
{
    string [] playerNames = {"Aaron", "Rick", "Josie"};
    var sim = new GameSimulator(playerNames, 1000000, 5000);
    var scores = sim.GetScores(5);
    var sorted = scores.OrderBy(c=>c.Score).Reverse();
    var top = sorted.Take(2);
    // uncomment if using linq pad
    //scores.Dump("scores");
    //sorted.Dump("sorted");
    //top.Dump("top");
}
class GameSimulator
{
    public GameSimulator(string [] playerNames, int maxScore, int maxLevel)
    {
        this.playerNames = playerNames;
        this.maxScore = maxScore;
        this.maxLevel = maxLevel;
    }
    private string [] playerNames;
    private int maxScore;
    private int maxLevel;
    public IEnumerable<ScoreBoardEntry> GetScores(int numGames)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numGames; i++)
        {
            string randomName = playerNames[random.Next(0, playerNames.Length-1)];
            int randomScore = random.Next(1, maxScore);
            int randomLevel = random.Next(1, maxLevel);
            yield return new ScoreBoardEntry(randomName, randomLevel, randomScore);
        }
    }
    static private Random random = new Random();
}
class ScoreBoardEntry
{
    public ScoreBoardEntry(string playerName, int levenNumber, int score)
    {
        PlayerName = playerName;
        LevelNumber = levenNumber;
        Score = score;
    }
    public string PlayerName { set; get; }
    public int LevelNumber { set; get; }
    public int Score { set; get; }
}
```